# Unable to run App on iPhone 5 after iOS 8.1 upgrade

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

Yesterday, I just upgraded the operating system on my iPhone 5 to the newest iOS 8.1. Thus far, Xcode 6 didn't include any support for that iOS version, so I had to update Xcode by simple downloading the latest version from AppStore (even though it was downloaded but the installation process didn't occur). Once it was done, I tried to run my project that worked perfectly for me yesterday and compilation went wrong, a little work with optional values unwrapping and got it complied. Running on my iPhone 5 and... a neat fatal error appears.

```
dyld`dyld_fatal_error:
0x1fe8e08c:  trap   
0x1fe8e090:  nop   



libdyld.dylib`dyld_stub_binder:
0x3666e080:  push   {r0, r1, r2, r3, r7, lr}
0x3666e084:  add    r7, sp, #0x10
0x3666e088:  ldr    r0, [sp, #24]
0x3666e08c:  ldr    r1, [sp, #28]
0x3666e090:  blx    0x3666e834                ; _dyld_fast_stub_entry(void*, long)
0x3666e094:  mov    r12, r0
0x3666e098:  pop    {r0, r1, r2, r3, r7, lr}
0x3666e09c:  add    sp, sp, #0x8
0x3666e0a0:  bx     r12


let identifier = "TableViewCell"
```

(Above presented some stuff from debugger...)

On a simulator of iPhone 5 it works. What's the cause?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is solved. According to Apple documentation over iOS 8.1.1 release:

Known Issue
If you have upgraded to the 8.1.1 Beta from iOS 8 Betas you may see your apps crashing due to provisioning profile issues.

***Workaround***:

- Connect the device via USB to your Mac
- Launch Xcode
- Choose Window -> Devices
- Right click on the device in left column, choose "Show Provisioning Profiles"
- Click on the provisioning profile in question
- Press the "-" button
- Continue to removing all affected profiles.
- Re-install the app

And do not forget to clean the product.

**Xcode -> Product -> Clean**

Hope it helps! :)